# conditionally close file on exit from function

Tags: python

I have a (recursive) function which I would like to accept either a string or an opened file object.  If the argument is a string, then the function opens a file and uses that file object.  It seems best to close this opened file object explicitly when I return from the function, but only if a string was passed in.  (Imagine the surprise from the user when they pass in an opened file object and find that their file object was closed somewhere).  Here's what I'm currently using:

```
def read_file(f, param):
    do_close = isinstance(f,basestring)
    f = open(f, 'rb') if do_close else f
    try:
        info = f.read(4)
        #check info here
        if info == Info_I_Want(param):
           return f.read(get_data(info))
        else:
           f.seek(goto_new_position(info))
           return read_file(f,param)
    except IKnowThisError:
           return None
    finally:
        if do_close:
           f.close()
```

You can assume that `IKnowThisError` will be raised at some point if I don't find the info I want.

This feels very kludgy.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not wrapping your recursive function with a wrapper to avoid overhead ?

```
def read_file(f, param):
    if isinstance(f, basestring):
        with open(f, 'rb') as real_f:
            return read_file2(real_f, param)
    else:
        return read_file2(real_f, param)

def read_file2(f, param):
    # Now f should be a file object
    ...
```

Comment: This could also be wrapped in a decorator.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- great point.  I don't write too many decorators, so I don't think of them particularly often. (other than the usual `classmethod`, `staticmethod`, `property` ... )

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- if I create a decorator (`string_file`) and decorate a recursive function, will I reach the recursion limit twice as fast?  (It shouldn't matter in this case -- I shouldn't get anywhere close to that limit.  I'm just curious and admittedly a little green when it comes to decorating)

Comment: @mgilson: This is actually a point of ongoing discussion among the Python developers:  You can only call the function recursively by its (global) name.  Each function call involves a global name lookup, and you will get back the decorated function.  This means not only you reach the recursion limit faster, but you have the overhead of the check and function call every time.  Of course you could circumvent this problem by using a different name for the decorated function.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- Thanks.  That's what I thought would happen.  Glad to see you've confirmed it.

Answer (score 2):

How about calling your function recursively?

```
def read_file(f, param):
    if isinstance(f, basestring):
        with open(f, 'rb') as real_f:
            return read_file(real_f, param)
    else:
        # normal path
```

Comment: Interesting idea -- It's seems a little weird to recursively call a recursive function in this way, but I kind of like it...

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming Python 3.3 offers a more general solution for this kind of problem, namely [`contextlib.ExitStack`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack).  This allow to conditionally add context managers to the current with-block:

```
def read_file(f, param):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        if isinstance(f, basestring):
            f = stack.enter_context(open(f, 'rb'))
        # Your code here
```